# ng-paste and onpaste, how to preserve/get existing text while pasting new text

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-paste

I'm using `ng-paste` and `onpaste` like this,

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" ng-trim="false" ng-model="x.value" select-on-click ng-paste="paste($event, x)" onpaste="return false;" id="input{{$index}}"
```

The `input` has text `some<CURSOR>data` (where the `<CURSOR>` represents the position of the cursor)

When I press <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> the paste event is called,

```
$scope.paste = function(event, data) {
      console.log('paste event', event);
}
```

It works, but I can only get the pasted text, what I want is `some<PASTED DATA>data`, any ideas?

P.S I had to use `onpaste="return false;"`, otherwise the text become `<PASTED DATA><PASTED DATA>`

Answer (score 0):

You could use input element's selectionStart/selectionEnd properties to do the trick.

```
   function onPaste(event) {
            var input = event.target;
            var start = input.selectionStart;
            var end = input.selectionEnd;
            var originString = input.value;
            var myContent = "<PASTED DATA>";
            input.value = originString.substring(0, start) + myContent + originString.substring(end, originString.length);
            event.preventDefault();
            var currentPosition = (originString.substring(0, start) + myContent ).length;
            setTimeout(function () {
                input.focus();
                input.setSelectionRange(currentPosition, currentPosition);
            }, 0);
        }
```